# How do I make the QuerySet filter use an overloaded comparison operator?

Tags: python-3.x, django, sqlite, django-queryset, comparison-operators

I have a model with a `OneToOneField` pointing to a parameter model. The latter overloads the python comparison operators, such as `<`.

**models.py:**

```
class SomeComplexParameter(models.Model):
    fid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    ...
    param = models.OneToOneField(SomeComplexParameter,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ...
```

When I try to filter `SomeModel` querysets by chaining `param__lt`, the overloaded `__lt__` method does not get invoked!

**For example:**

If I define a threshold `SomeComplexParameter` instance

```
p_threshold = SomeComplexParameter.objects.create(value=30)
```

and filter `SomeModel` querysets using

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(param__lt=p_threshold)
```

it returns random set of `SomeModel` instances each time.

**What I tried so far:**

```
print(SomeModel.objects.filter(param__lt=p_threshold).query)
```

yields

```
SELECT "bricks_somemodel"."fid", "bricks_somemodel"."param_id" FROM "bricks_somemodel" WHERE "bricks_somemodel"."param_id" < 68e1c73401c5412bb91f4cb75ce57e8e
```

which points to the fact that Django isn't using the overloaded operator. Instead it's comparing the uuids (pk for this model). This explains the randomness!

I checked that

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(param__value__lt=30)
```

filters correctly, as it uses the native python `<` operator. But this won't be an option for me, as I must use the overloaded `__lt__` method on `SomeComplexParameter`.

Is there some way to configure my models so that filtering with `param__lt=p_threshold` uses the overridden `__lt__` operator?

*Version info*: Django 3.2.13, Python 3.9.0, sqlite

Comment: You can't do this. The `__lt__` is only used for comparisons in Python itself - it has nothing to do with the database query that is generated when you use `__lt` in a queryset filter. Django simply instructs the database to do the comparison, and returns the result provided by the database.

Comment: @solarissmoke, that's very helpful! I take it from your response that the QuerySet API doesn't look for overloaded comparison operators when generating database queries. By contrast, a `SomeModel` instance comparison like `o1 < o2` works because it's really just a Python comparison. Does this sound accurate?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. You can do such comparisons in Python between two model instances, but when filtering on a queryset, the overloaded operator cannot be used because the database engine has no knowledge of Python.